# En clausula where no discrimina una resta

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hola tengo la siguiente consulta ES Bastante extensa pero es mas o menos así

```
Select
 CantidadEmpacada, 
 CantidadFacturada
FROM PedidoEmpaque
WHERE (CantidadEmpacada - CantidadFacturada) > 0
```

me arroja 2 filas pero cuando se cumple la resta es igual a cero siguen saliendo las misma 2 filas
He probado usando también <> 0 y  != 0 pero los resultados son los mismos.

**EDICION** Coloco los datos para ejemplo @Lamak y @mauricioalvarez la cuestion es que en sql me esta mostrando todos los datos!!

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PedidoEmpaque](
[NroPedido] [varchar](7) NOT NULL,
[IdReferenciaTamano] [int] NULL,
[CodigoTercero] [varchar](6) NOT NULL,
[RazonSocial] [varchar](100) NULL,
[NombreSucursal] [varchar](50) NULL,
[CantidadCancelada] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
[DescuentoAdicionales] [decimal](6, 3) NULL,
[CantidadEmpacada] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
[CantidadFacturada] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
[PrecioUsuario] [decimal](9, 2) NOT NULL,
[Descuento] [decimal](6, 3) NULL,
[PrecioLista] [decimal](9, 2) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY];

 INSERT [dbo].[PedidoEmpaque] ([NroPedido], [IdReferenciaTamano], 
 [CodigoTercero], [RazonSocial], [NombreSucursal], [CantidadCancelada], 
 [DescuentoAdicionales], [CantidadEmpacada],[CantidadFacturada], 
 [PrecioUsuario], [Descuento], [PrecioLista]) VALUES (N'46', 47734, 
 N'000019', 
 N'GAMMA COLORS', N'SUCURSAL PRINCIPAL', CAST(0.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), 
 CAST(0.000 AS Decimal(6, 3)), CAST(0.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), CAST(0.00 AS 
 Decimal(18, 2)),CAST(0.00 AS Decimal(9, 2)), CAST(0.000 AS Decimal(6, 3)), 
 CAST(43920.00 AS Decimal(9, 2)));
 INSERT [dbo].[PedidoEmpaque] ([NroPedido], [IdReferenciaTamano], 
 [CodigoTercero], [RazonSocial], [NombreSucursal], [CantidadCancelada], 
 [DescuentoAdicionales], [CantidadEmpacada],[CantidadFacturada], 
 [PrecioUsuario], [Descuento], [PrecioLista]) VALUES (N'49', 51964, 
 N'000019', N'GAMMA COLORS', N'SUCURSAL PRINCIPAL', CAST(0.00 AS Decimal(18, 
 2)), CAST(0.000 AS Decimal(6, 3)), CAST(500.00 AS Decimal(18, 
 2)),CAST(500.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), CAST(0.00 AS Decimal(9, 2)), CAST(0.000 
 AS Decimal(6, 3)), CAST(2479.00 AS Decimal(9, 2)));
 INSERT [dbo].[PedidoEmpaque] ([NroPedido], [IdReferenciaTamano], 
 [CodigoTercero], [RazonSocial], [NombreSucursal], [CantidadCancelada], 
 [DescuentoAdicionales], [CantidadEmpacada],[CantidadFacturada], 
 [PrecioUsuario], [Descuento], [PrecioLista]) VALUES (N'48', 52801, 
 N'005090', N'ALMACE BON AIR', N'SUCURSAL 01', CAST(0.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), 
 CAST(0.000 AS Decimal(6, 3)), CAST(0.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), CAST(0.00 AS 
 Decimal(18, 2)),CAST(0.00 AS Decimal(9, 2)), CAST(0.000 AS Decimal(6, 3)), 
 CAST(0.00 AS Decimal(9, 2)));
 INSERT [dbo].[PedidoEmpaque] ([NroPedido], [IdReferenciaTamano], 
  [CodigoTercero], [RazonSocial], [NombreSucursal], [CantidadCancelada], 
 [DescuentoAdicionales], [CantidadEmpacada],[CantidadFacturada], 
[PrecioUsuario], [Descuento], [PrecioLista]) VALUES (N'49', 34660, 
N'000019', N'GAMMA COLORS', N'SUCURSAL PRINCIPAL', CAST(0.00 AS Decimal(18, 
2)), CAST(0.000 AS Decimal(6, 3)), CAST(300.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), 
CAST(250.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)),CAST(0.00 AS Decimal(9, 2)), CAST(0.000 AS 
Decimal(6, 3)), CAST(4032.00 AS Decimal(9, 2)));
INSERT [dbo].[PedidoEmpaque] ([NroPedido], [IdReferenciaTamano], 
[CodigoTercero], [RazonSocial], [NombreSucursal], [CantidadCancelada], 
[DescuentoAdicionales], [CantidadEmpacada],[CantidadFacturada], 
[PrecioUsuario], [Descuento], [PrecioLista]) VALUES (N'46', 47734, 
N'000019', N'GAMMA COLORS', N'SUCURSAL PRINCIPAL', CAST(0.00 AS Decimal(18, 
2)), CAST(0.000 AS Decimal(6, 3)), CAST(458.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), 
CAST(458.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)),CAST(0.00 AS Decimal(9, 2)), CAST(0.000 AS 
Decimal(6, 3)), CAST(43920.00 AS Decimal(9, 2)));
INSERT [dbo].[PedidoEmpaque] ([NroPedido], [IdReferenciaTamano], 
[CodigoTercero], [RazonSocial], [NombreSucursal], [CantidadCancelada], 
[DescuentoAdicionales], [CantidadEmpacada],[CantidadFacturada], 
[PrecioUsuario], [Descuento], [PrecioLista]) VALUES (N'51', -1, N'000033', 
N'CONFECCIONES D.LOLITA', N'SUCURSAL PRINCIPAL', CAST(0.00 AS Decimal(18, 
2)), CAST(0.000 AS Decimal(6, 3)), CAST(0.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)),CAST(0.00 AS 
Decimal(18, 2)), CAST(1000.00 AS Decimal(9, 2)), CAST(0.000 AS Decimal(6, 
3)), CAST(0.00 AS Decimal(9, 2)));
```

lo ideal es que me muestre el resultado así como me sale en [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f9a9d/1)

Comment: suena a algo que no debe pasar, tienes datos de ejemplo?, o mostrarnos los resultados que estás obteniendo?

Comment: ¿Puedes agregar ejemplos de los datos de las tablas, así como los resultados esperados de la consulta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me da la impresión que tienes uno de dos problemas:
1. Los datos no son del mismo tipo, por lo que recomiendo que lo conviertas

```
...
where (convert(float, CantidadEmpacada) - convert(float, CantidadFacturada)) > 0.00
```

2. Tienes algún valor null en el resultado de tus datos

...

```
where (isnull(CantidadEmpacada, 0) - isnull(CantidadFacturada, 0)) > 0.00
```

De igual forma sería bueno que pusieras la estructura de la tabla y algunos datos de ejemplo.

Comment: @gbianchi, pues lo de elena fue acertado y he colocado una estructura y datos de ejemplo. no entiendo porque votaste encontra o desfavoreciendo la pregunta?

Comment: Si quieres puedes cambiar la estructura de la tabla y poner valores por defecto = 0 para esas columnas

Comment: si ya realice ISNULL(CantidadEmpacada, 0) y un cast(CantidadEmpacada as decimal...) fue como me resulto la consulta Gracias @ElenaLópez